# package.json - prohibit usage of some filenames in a package sources

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

I'm looking for a way to check the list of files in the `src` folder of a package before publishing/pushing.

I want to prohibit the usage of files with certain extensions/glob patterns or provide a pattern for acceptable filenames. How can I achieve that?

I'd expect a simple tool similar to [pkg-ok](https://github.com/typicode/pkg-ok) existing for this but can't figure a search request that won't send me to something completely different.

I know there is a `filenames` plugin for ESlint (`eslint-plugin-filenames`). But I want this check to be separate from ESlint. (I want to configure paths for ESlint and any other tools with only valid files in mind.)

Comment: Consider writing a custom tool for this using the [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) package. For example, something like this contrived [filename-check.js](https://paste.ee/p/SNTty) that searches the `src` directory - If it finds any files with a `.txt` or `.md` file suffix it produces an error, and lists the impermissible files. You'll need to define the correct glob pattern for your scenario. Also you can invoke it via an npm script. E.g. In your _package.json_ add the following: `"scripts": { "checkNames": "node filename-check.js" }` - Then run `npm run checkNames`

Comment: Yep, that's the last (and so far the only) option in the list. I'm already pretty deep in the rabbit hole of writing node packages to enable other node packages, so I'm not picking this one myself yet, since it's pretty minor.